# How Pass Some Values To Catch Method From OutSide try/catch

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, methods, parameters, try-catch

please see these sample codes:

```
try
{
      string str = MyMethod();
}
catch
{

}
public string MyMethod()
{
     CookieContainer cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
     ... -> Some Codes That Make An Exception
}
```

How Can I Pass cookieJar To Catch Method?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You make a new

```
public class CookieJarException : Exception
    {
        public CookieJar Jar {get; private set;}

        public CookieJarException(CookieJar a)
        {
            Jar = a;
        }

    }
```

and then you

```
throw new CookieJarException(cookieJar);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. By making it a global variable.
2. By defining your own exception class that inherits from `System.Exception` with a property to hold `cookieJar`. You then would have a `try/catch` in `MyMethod()` that would catch any exception and raise that `CookieLovingException` instead, setting the property and `InnerException`.
   Then the outer handler would `catch CookieLovingException ex`.

Comment: +1 Option 2 should always be the preferred approach. Friends don't let friends catch (or throw) System.Exception

Answer (score -2):

You can use  finally block here. finally is always executed

```
        public string MyMethod()
        {
            CookieContainer cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
            try
            {

                // Some Codes That Make An Exception
                string str = MyMethod();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                 if (cookieJar != null)
                {
                    // do whatever u want
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (cookieJar != null)
                {
                    // do whatever u want
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: 1. Doesn't compile, 2. Infinite recursion, 3. cookieJar null guards are redundant, 4. Changes the semantics of what the OP was asking (moves the exception handling into the method)